# exporting TensorFlow model with no variables

Tags: tensorflow, keras

i am exporting Keras TF model without a luck:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

ssValues = np.zeros(shape=(640,800,6),dtype=np.float16)
ssValues += 3.

ssKerasConstant = tf.keras.backend.constant(value=ssValues, dtype=tf.dtypes.float16, shape=(1,640,800,6));
inputLayer = tf.keras.Input(shape=(640,800,6),
                            name='inputLayer',
                            batch_size=None,
                            dtype=tf.dtypes.float16)

ssConstant = tf.constant(ssValues, dtype=tf.dtypes.float16, shape=(1,640,800,6), name='ss')
ssm = tf.keras.layers.Multiply()([inputLayer,ssKerasConstant])
model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=inputLayer, outputs=ssm)
tf.keras.experimental.export_saved_model(model, '~/models/model7.pb')
```

and i get the following error:
 graph = inputs[0].graph
IndexError: list index out of range

even though i am able to predict the model.

Comment: The code snippet you provided works  successfully in TF 2.0 nightly version '2.0.0-dev20191002'. However this function is deprecated. So you may have to save the model in checkpoint format and further use ```freeze_graph.py``` to convert into frozen model.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the model successfully by replacing the last line of your code,

```
tf.keras.experimental.export_saved_model(model, '~/models/model7.pb')
```

with the below line:

```
tf.saved_model.save(model, '~/models/model7.pb')
```

It works in Tensorflow Version, 2.0. Please find Gist [here](https://colab.sandbox.google.com/gist/rmothukuru/e9d5c7775b3b1c92bdde35930fec8680/so_57979546.ipynb).